# Creating dynamic columns and data binding

Tags: c#, listview, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView to display information regarding virtual machines and each virtual machine has a different set of drives attached to it. During my data gathering, I get all of the info and store it in a Disk_Drive object with the properties that I care for (size,serial,usage,etc), now I want to dynamically create the columns and then bind the data using AddObjects. How would I do this?

I am not sure what the aspect getter should be in this scenario as it will not be unique, how can I handle this?

```
public void GenerateColumns(Model.HyperVTools.VMInfo vmObject)
        {
            objectListView2.Columns.Clear();
            objectListView2.Items.Clear();
            List<OLVColumn> columnsList = new List<OLVColumn>();

            OLVColumn vmhostnameColumn = new OLVColumn("Hostname", "Host");

            //vhd columns
            foreach (var disk in vmObject.DisksList)
            {
                string text = string.Format("{0};{1}GB;{2}GB;", disk.Path, disk.SizeReadable,
                        disk.MaxVHDSizeReadable);
                disk.FormattedVHDInfo = text;

                OLVColumn diskColumn = new OLVColumn("Attached VHD", "FormattedVHDInfo");
                columnsList.Add(diskColumn);
            }

            columnsList.Add(vmhostnameColumn);

            objectListView2.Columns.AddRange(columnsList.Cast<System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader>().ToArray());

            objectListView2.AddObject(vmObject);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        DataTable dtInput = new DataTable();
        dtInput = dsAnalystPage.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataColumn cl in dtInput.Columns)
        {

            BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn aNewColumn = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn();
            aNewColumn.Name = cl.ColumnName;
            aNewColumn.Text = cl.ColumnName;
            if (aNewColumn.Text == "ASF_Code" || aNewColumn.Text == "ASD_SheetCode" || aNewColumn.Text == "ASD_SheetName")
            {
                aNewColumn.Width = 0;
                aNewColumn.IsVisible = false;
            }
            OLV.AllColumns.Add(aNewColumn);
            OLV.RebuildColumns();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the control.

```
OLV.Reset();
```